# ContentByQueryWebPart filter show all items if filter value not set

Tags: content-query-web-part

I have a question about CQWP. Iam working on blog CQWP that shows the latest 5 blogs. The site has one entry page and 4 pages dedicated to authors. All of these 5 pages has page layout with content type and there is a lookup to 'authors' list.
The problem is following:
I would like to use one web part on all of these 5 pages, so on entry page (no author dedicated) it should show 5 latest blogs from all authors however if i place this wp to author dedicated page (lookup points to author) i want that wp shows only blogs from this author. I use PageFieldValue filter.

Now i ended with 2 wp's:one that has no filter and show the 5 latests blogs from all authors and one that has filter based on pagefieldvalue.

I would like to end with 1 web part that could be used on all 5 pages.

Any recommendations? Thanks